# Test level testng XML parameter is not getting updated

Tags: java, selenium, testng

We have a parameter declared at test level (2 or more tests) in TestNG XML as shown below.

```
<test name="Regression Tests - Test1">
    <parameter name="TestData" value = "Sample.xls" />
    <parameter name="VaultName" value = "Test Vault" />
    <parameter name="RestoreVault" value = "Test1" />
    <groups>
        <run>
            <exclude name="Bug"></exclude>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="Project.Tests.RegTest1"/>
     </classes>
</test>

<test name="Regression Tests - Test2">
    <parameter name="TestData" value = "Sample.xls" />
    <parameter name="VaultName" value = "Test Vault" />
    <parameter name="RestoreVault" value = "Test2" />
    <groups>
        <run>
            <exclude name="Bug"></exclude>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="Project.Tests.RegTest2"/>
     </classes>
</test>
```

The parameter values are access at the script using below code

```
function test () {
  XmlTest xmlParameters = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest();
  String param1 = xmlParameters.getParameter("RestoreVault");
}
```

Value for param1 is read correctly as 'Test1' but on executing second test, value remains same as 'Test1' not as 'Test2'.

Could you let us know the reason or suggestions here.

Comment: We can suppose it's an issue (could you open a new issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues ?). But why not using `@Parameters` instead? http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. We are trying to access value of this parameter at @BeforeSuite.

Answer (score 0):

Use <methods> instead, because when using <groups> then parameters are not passed correctly from the 2nd test - it workded for me:

```
<test name="tests2">
    <parameter name="filter.tags" value="@yourTag"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.your.TestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name="myTestMethod"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```